# MVC htaccess not working

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, .htaccess, wamp

Their are multiple related questions and answers to this but am still  unable to get my application running.

I have two applications in my project folder called **PROGMAN**, one is mvc and the other traditional coded php. However the non mvc app runs well while the mvc app throws **URL not Found Error**

Here is how my application folder is organised.The

```
   PROGMAN

           index.php
           NON MVC APP----runs

           MVC APPLICATIN
                      application
                      .htaccess
                      index.php
```

The .htaccess file of the mvc app is

```
   Options -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine On
   Options -Indexes
   RewriteBase /PROGMAN/mvcapp/
   # General rewrite rules
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I hope rewrite module is enabled in your webserver

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite is working/ enabled in apache